# ffprobe run command for multiple videos

Tags: text-processing

I am currently running this command for each video file ending in .mp4 in directory /home/videos to output the running time of each one in /root/videoduration.txt

```
ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -sexagesimal '/home/videos/video1.mp4' | awk -F: '{printf "%02d:%02d:%02d",$1,$2,$3}' >> /root/videoduration.txt && sed -i -e '$a\' /root/videoduration.txt
```

How am I able to do this for every video in a directory ending in .mp4 only outputing the duration. The script needs to go in alphabetical order.

Answer (score -1):

You need to wrap your command in a loop.
Sorry, not sure what your `sed` does and if it would be appropriate at the end of the loop or needs to happen after each `ffprobe` (if so, it may be best to pass the output of `ffprobe` to `sed` rather than running `sed` on the resulting file).

Sample loop:

```
for file in $( ls -1 -Q /home/videos/*.mp4 | sort ); do
  ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -sexagesimal $file | awk -F: '{printf "%02d:%02d:%02d",$1,$2,$3}' >> /root/videoduration.txt && sed -i -e '$a\' /root/videoduration.txt
done
```

or

```
while read file; do
  ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -sexagesimal $file | awk -F: '{printf "%02d:%02d:%02d",$1,$2,$3}' >> /root/videoduration.txt && sed -i -e '$a\' /root/videoduration.txt
done < <( ls -1 -Q /home/videos/*.mp4 | sort )
```

Comment: surely there will be great topics on how to properly do loops here in SE somewhere :-)

Comment: Is this just for .mp4 files?

Comment: sorry, missed that -- same concept, just change the `ls` to include `/home/videos/*.mp4`

Comment: `for file in $( ls -1 -Q /home/videos/*.mp4 | sort )` should be much better written `for file in /home/videos/*.mp4`